# SQLite Database Error Newbie

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is my first SQLite App and I found a lot of errors and I don't what to do.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do?

This is my log cat:

```
12-26 18:58:05.870 26185-26185/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-26 18:58:05.889 26185-26185/? E/Environment: initForCurrentUser:userId= 0
12-26 18:58:05.889 26185-26185/? D/Environment: UserEnvironment current 
userId IS : 0
12-26 18:58:05.889 26185-26185/? D/Environment: UserEnvironment PRIMARY 
STORAGE IS : MEDIA_INTERNAL
12-26 18:58:05.982 26185-26185/com.example.acer.sqlitecrud I/LoadedApk: No 
resource references to update in package com.hmct.hmcttheme
12-26 18:58:06.010 26185-26185/com.example.acer.sqlitecrud W/art: Before 
Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
12-26 18:58:06.135 26185-26185/com.example.acer.sqlitecrud E/SQLiteLog: (1) 
near "TABLEstudentTable": syntax error
12-26 18:58:06.136 26185-26185/com.example.acer.sqlitecrud D/AndroidRuntime: 
Shutting down VM
12-26 18:58:06.138 26185-26185/com.example.acer.sqlitecrud E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.acer.sqlitecrud, PID: 26185

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.acer.sqlitecrud/com.example.acer.sqlitecrud.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEstudentTable": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEstudentTable(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, MARKS INTEGER)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2328)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5270)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:708)
                                                                          Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEstudentTable": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEstudentTable(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, MARKS INTEGER)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
                                                                             at com.example.acer.sqlitecrud.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:27)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                                             at com.example.acer.sqlitecrud.DatabaseHelper.<init>(DatabaseHelper.java:22)
                                                                             at com.example.acer.sqlitecrud.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6075)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2281)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5270) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:708) 
12-26 18:58:06.249 26185-26185/com.example.acer.sqlitecrud I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26185 SIG: 9
```

This is my class:

**DatabaseHelper.Java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String dbName = "Student.db";
public static final String tbName = "studentTable";
public static final String colID = "ID";
public static final String colName = "NAME";
public static final String colMarks = "MARKS";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, dbName, null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE"+tbName+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, MARKS INTEGER)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+tbName);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData (String Name, String Marks){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(colName,Name);
    contentValues.put(colMarks,Marks);
    long result = db.insert(tbName,null,contentValues);

    if (result == -1){
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.acer.sqlitecrud;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper myDb;
EditText Name, Marks;
Button addData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtNama);
    Marks = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtNilai);
    addData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);

    InsertData();

}

private void InsertData() {
    addData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(Name.getText().toString(),
                    Marks.getText().toString());

            if (isInserted = true){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Telah Di Inputkan !!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Gagal Di Inputkan !!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I see the question was already answered but, being you are new in developing I recommend you always double check the stack trace. The source of the error was clear there. Anyway, if you works with databases, SQLite or any other, keep a local instance to test your queries. Many times will be of use. Good Luck!!

Comment: yeah, thank you.
i didnt know that it need same space before i put my table name hehe

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+tbName+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, MARKS INTEGER)");
}
```

note the space between the TABLE and tbName

Answer (score 0):

check below code

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+tbName+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, MARKS INTEGER)"); //add space after TABLE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Query syntax error, space is missing.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+tbName+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,      NAME TEXT, MARKS INTEGER)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing space in syntax of create table

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+tbName+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, MARKS INTEGER)");
```

In drop table also you missed the space

```
"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+tbName
```